# Sublime Text 2: Key stroke to recognize a single space variable

Tags: sublimetext2

I have something like this

```
    private void radioButton8_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton8.Checked == true)
        { }
    }

    private void radioButton9_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton9.Checked == true)
        { }
    }

    private void radioButton10_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (radioButton10.Checked == true)
        {}
    }
```

And using ctrl + H i wanna find all text that is similar to
      private void radioButtonX_CheckedChanged
where X can be anything

Comment: Did you try the regex find+replace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this Regular Expression:

```
private void radioButton.*?_CheckedChanged
```

Just remember to tell Sublime Text that this is a Regular Expression (the `.*` button in the find panel).